# Trouble reading ints (well chars and then converting) from text file one line at a time in C++

Tags: c++

I have read different posts/questions on here as well as cplusplus.com and various sources and am still having trouble with my code as far as reading a text file. The text file has one int (single digit) on each line. So for example:
5
1
2
5
.
.
.
etc
Each number is supposed to represent a specific variable. I am having trouble I believe it's with the '\n' character? Because it will read the first int but then the second one and a few others will be -38!! I've tried the ignore() thing (although maybe I did that wrong?) and that didn't work. I'm sure it's a quick fix and probably staring me in the face but I can't see it! Here is the part of my code that I'm having issues with:

```
void RegOffice::analyzeFile()
{
    cout << "Please enter the location of the file to be read. " << endl;
    cin >> fileName;
    cout << endl;
    inData.open(fileName.c_str());

    if (inData.is_open())
    //while file is open
    {
        while(inData)       //While file is still good
        {
            char c;

            /* 
            The function below reads in one int at a time on each line. First line is the number of windows
            open. The next line will be the time (or clock tick) at which the next student(s) arrive. 
            The next line will be the number of students that arrive at that time. The lines after that
            will be the amount of time each student needs at a window in minutes.
            */

            c = inData.get();               //Gets the number of windows open
            winOpen = c - '0';  
            cout << "Windows Open: " << winOpen << endl;            
            windows = new GenQueue<Window>(winOpen);    //Sets up an array of open windows
            c = inData.get();
            time = c - '0';     //Gets the first time that students arrive
            cout << "Time: " << time << endl;   
            c = inData.get();
            numStudents = int(c - '0');     //Gets the number of students that enter the line at that time
            cout << "Number of Students: " << numStudents + 1 << endl;  

            for(int i = 0; i < numStudents; i++)    // numStudents is the number read in by the text file
            {
                Student *stu = new Student(); //creating a new instance of a student
                c = inData.get();
                stu->setTimeAtWin(c - '0');  //Setting student's wait time to the next number in file
                stu->setArrivalTime(time);   //Setting student's arrival time
                cout << "New Student created! Info for Student #" << i << ":" << endl;
                stu->print();
                line->addBack(*stu);   
            //Inserting that student to the back of the queue (The first student                                                       
            //will be first in line though if no one is in line)

            }
        }
     }
  }
```

Comment: I don't understand why you are sometimes casting the result of the subtraction to `int` and at other times not. Are you sure the input file contains only integers on a line by themselves. Finally, how is `inData` defined?

Comment: Based on what I've researched.. That's how I thought you had to convert a char to an int. in the examples i saw it showed a char declared/assigned first and then an int that was assigned to that char value. And inData is defined as the file opened based on the users input. I will update the code to include that part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you reading from an ifstream?

```
#include <fstream>
std::ifstream infile("inData.txt");
```

Then to read a line, do

```
int c;
infile >> c;
```

Comment: Yes I am. I will try that.

Answer (score 0):

I see the problem now. From [this reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/get/) the function `istream::get()` has this prototype: `int get();` I think you can see how that might not work in your program.

Comment: Oh so if I did use that would I not need to assign a char to it first? I could just directly assign it to an int variable? such as int c =  inData.get()

Comment: Looks like it. Ccccccccc